# Can't read data from JSON file

Tags: angular

Please I have a problem here. I can't read the data from a JSON file:

```
<i>{{ exform.get('firstname').hasError("required") ? "{{ 'hospitaladmin.firstname.error.required' | translate }}" : '' }}</i>
```

But here it works:

```
 placeholder="{{ 'hospitaladmin.search' | translate }}"
```

Any idea about it?

Comment: remove the single quotes. when you use "interpolation" (the `{{` `}}`) inside you use variables -without quotes- or string fixed -with quotes- your epresion try to translate the string "hospitaladmin.firstname.error.required", **not** the value of the variable `hospitaladmin.firstname.error.required`

Comment: you need use "safe operaror" futhermore is "errors"

Comment: with () it solved the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rewrite your expression a little bit to keep things simple:

```
<i>{{ exform.get('firstname').hasError("required") ? (hospitaladmin.firstname.error.required | translate) : '' }}</i>
```

And for your [placeholder](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding):

```
[placeholder]="hospitaladmin.search | translate"
```